# What is the RESTful way to express two ways of querying a list of resources?

Tags: ajax, api, rest, design-patterns, comet

Imagine I'm building a product to keep track of bank transactions, and we support `GET /transactions/{id}` which allows you to retrieve a specific transaction.

We also have a client which displays lists of transactions, so we allow a `GET` to `/transactions` which by default returns the last 100 transactions you are able to access as a JSON array. A common use case for our site is to get a list of transactions around a fixed point. To support this, we have a few GET parameters:

- `anchor`: the *id* to use as the centre point
- `number_before`: how many transactions before the `anchor` to return
- `number_after`: how many transactions after the `anchor` to return.

It would be nice if we could allow the clients to stay up-to-date about transactions via some sort of [longpolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).

I'd like to implement a request where clients can say "This is the last *id* I have, return when you have one or more transactions greater than this.", and the server would block (or return immediately if a non-blocking call was requested) until it had something to return.

Should this be also a `GET` to `/transactions` with a different set of parameters, like `last_txn` instead of the aformentioned, or is overloading a URI like that bad, and I should make it a GET to `/transactions/+latest` or something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no 100% ideologically correct option and the REST style doesnt describe this moment, so it is up to you.

But I would suggest using `/transactions` with different parameters: you are keeping concept of method overloading that is quite natural for programmers.